# Fitting a Gaussian process to a collection of curves

Tags: gaussian-process

I have some time series data represented by a collection of curves, as shown in the following diagram,[image]

I want to determine the mean and covariance over time of this collection of curves. I don't know where to start, any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Are these actually curves, or was this plot generated by plotting points and then connecting them with line segments? If it's the latter, you could do worse than just dumping all the points into a standard GP.

Comment: @Sycorax Thanks for the comment. It is the latter case. How would I proceed with the problem given the collection of points? I've read about Gaussian process regression (with noisy data?), is this relevant here?